# Compile problem when using keyword 'new' on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following line of code in my Arduino sketch:

```
static double *temps = new double[arraySize];  //Declare array to hold tempratures, place the array on the heap where it will not be deleted and keep the pointer as a static
//double temps[arraySize];
```

When I compile with the Arduino IDE on Ubuntu it compiles just fine. However, when I compile on the Raspberry Pi, it throws up the following error:

```
xxx.cpp.o: In function `last Function in file()':
xxx.cpp:[last line in file]: undefined referance to `operator new[] (unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this a bug? If so, how do I report it? If not, why is it throwing this error or how else can I declare a static array of doubles (needs to be static, I calculate an average of some incoming data over several function calls)?

Comment: What version of arduino is the Pi running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino uses [AVR libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) which does not provide a complete C++ environment.

Among other things AVR libc does not support `new` and `delete`. See the [FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus) for more information.

Some versions of the Arduino libraries may provide new and delete but they are just wrappers around `malloc` and `free`. I suggest not using new and delete on arduino because they do not have the same behavior as C++. For example destructors will not be called on the arduino when delete is called.

Answer (score 0):

> how else can I declare a static array of doubles (needs to be static,
>   I calculate an average of some incoming data over several function
>   calls)

When you find a bug in the Arduino software, please do report it to the appropriate place -- http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ContactUs has the contact details.

One way to declare a static array of doubles is like this:

```
double boxcar_average(double new_sample) {
  const int arraySize = 3;
  static double old_sample[ arraySize ] = {0};
  double sum = new_sample;
  for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
    sum += old_sample[i];
  }
  old_sample[0] = old_sample[1];
  old_sample[1] = old_sample[2];
  old_sample[2] = new_sample;
  return( sum / 4 );
}
```